# How to replace text using powershell inside subdirectory text?

Tags: windows, powershell

i have text files in subdirectory

```
C:\a\aa.txt
C:\a\tab\aa.txt
C:\a\abc\aa.txt
```

this is the command i have

```
(Get-Content C:\a\*.txt) -creplace '(?s)^.*/', '' | Set-Content C:\a\*.txt
```

but it will replace text only text file available inside `C:\a\`
how can tell powershell to read content inside sub directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use  `get-childitem` to iterate through the directories. Like so:

```
$items = get-childitem -path "C:\temp" -Recurse | ? { ! $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.extension -eq ".txt"}
foreach ($item in $items){
    (Get-content -path $item.fullname) -creplace '(?s)^.*/', '' | Set-Content $item.fullname
}
```

Notice the `-recurse` parameter.